# C++: use own class in a multiset container

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, containers, multiset

at first I'm new here and English isn't my native language so apologize for any grammatical failures but I find this community really nice so I will try to ask my question as precise as I can.

I want to add my own class object into a stl container multiset and want to sort it with my own overloaded less operator defined in my class. I really tried out several solutions but nothing really worked so I hope someone can give me some useful hints to solve it.

Here is my general idea of my class definition:

```
class object {
public:
    int first;
    string second;

    object(int f, string s) {
         first = f;
         second = s;
    }

    bool operator<(const object &comp) {
        return first < comp.first;
        }
};
```

This was my first try and it didn't work so I also tried out to declare the overloaded operator as a friend method but it didn't work also.

Here is a short code extract from my main function:

```
includes ...
//code omitted
int main() {
    multiset<object*> mmset;

    mmset.insert(new object(10, "test"));
    mmset.insert(new object(11, "test"));

    return 0;
 }
```

After a while I started to debugging my code and try to figure out where the problem is and I come across the following thing that have made me a bit suspicious.

code extract from the stl:

```
// TEMPLATE STRUCT less
template<class _Ty>
struct less : public binary_function<_Ty, _Ty, bool>
    {   // functor for operator<
    bool operator()(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right) const
    {   // apply operator< to operands
          return (_Left < _Right);
    }
    };
```

I have set a breakpoint on this line and observed what the program is doing here and I don't know why, but it only compares the addresses from the two objects and return so always false. It never calls my overloaded less operator although the operator exists and the _Left and _Right variables contain the address to my object.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Best Greetings

Tom

Comment: Concerning your first attempt, what do you mean by "it didn't work"? Didn't compile? Crashed at run-time? Didn't give expected results? What was the error message?

Comment: yes of course this was a bit vague. I meant that it doesn't give the expected results. The program itself runs without any errors it is just that it doesn't sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not storing `object`s in your `multiset`. You are storing `object*`s. These are pointers to `object`s. This means the set will order the pointers that you're inserting into it.

It seems like you really just want a `multiset<object>`:

```
multiset<object> mmset;
mmset.emplace(10, "test");
mmset.emplace(11, "test");
```

Now it will use `<` to compare the `object`s themselves.

If you really want to store pointers, you'll need to provide a custom comparator to the `multiset`. In C++11, you can do this easily with a lambda:

```
auto f = [](int* a, int* b) { return *a < *b; };
std::multiset<int*, decltype(f)> mmset(f);
```

Pre-C++11, you can create a function object that implements `operator()` with the same body as this lambda function.

Comment: He probably needs to make his `operator<` `const` too.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!! Yes something like this I have already feared... But there must be a solution to solve this problem without inserting the whole objects directly into the set. It's not very efficient to copy a complete object into a set. Especially if the size of the objects grows. It's just a prototype and I will soon add more datatypes to my object.

Comment: @user2372782 I'll add the solution if you really want to contain pointers. Watch for an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help. That's seems to be a good solution to solve this problem.

I have searched a bit deeper in the new C++11 standard and found out that there is another possible solution to solve this with a little bit simpler implementation but the same result :)
I will post it just as information for other seekers with the same problem.

You can pass any constructor a stl container a so-called comparison object which the container will use to arrange your content.
The only thing you have to do is to define the overloaded `operator()` in your class and "misuse" them as a comparison operator.

```
class object {
    int first;
    string second;

    object() { };
    object(int f, string s) {
       first = f;
       second = s;
    }

    bool operator()(const object *comp1, const object *comp2) const {
       return comp1->first < comp2->first;
    }
}
```

The other thing what you have additionally to do now is to pass the `object` as the second argument in your definition of the container:

```
multiset(object*, object) mmset;
```

You can also use an extra class for this purpose just for comparison because otherwise you need a default constructor to use this class in this way.