# Passing my compar function to std::multiset with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, lambda, multiset

I have a std::multiset, which stores std::pair. I want the first attribute to have no constraint on uniqueness, but I want the second one to be unique. So, I decided to pass my own function to multiset, in order to achieve this (if not please let me know).

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497414/c-use-own-class-in-a-multiset-container) answer, I wrote a similar function but it fails, and I have no idea why (no idea of λ - and I am Greek :) ).

```
auto f = [](std::pair<float, int>& a, std::pair<float, int>& b) {
  return (a.first < b.first && a.second != b.second);
};
```

Error:

```
error: expression ‘#‘lambda_expr’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>’ is not a constant-expression
sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers
error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

Comment: That means that I am on the wrong track @T.C.. What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand your uniqueness criterion. You're using a `multiset` so multiple keys that compare equal are going to be stored in the container.

Comment: I think the main problem is the lambda need to take `const &` or by value

Comment: The second attribute @Praetorian it's actually an id, while the first is some distance. I allow points with the same distance, but I don't want same points in the results. The multiset actually stores the resulted vectors of multithreading.

Comment: But if you only want unique *points*, shouldn't you be using a `set` instead?

Comment: But the criterion is for sorting is the distance......and oops! Now that my head thought of compar functions, I see my mistake.

Comment: Haven't really thought of it. Direct access is not something that bothers me for this issue. You see the multiset is going to be looped, so I don't see the reason to use a `map`. If you do, let me know @TonyD

Comment: Surely the distance is constant for any given point, so any attempt to re-add the same point will be exactly the same pair and could be excluded simply by using a `set` - given you want ordering by distance simply putting that first in the `pair` is all you need to do - the default sorting order is already appropriate. (I deleted my comment re `map<point,distance>` when I saw your need for sorting by distance)

Comment: Your earlier comment seems to indicate you think multiset has something to do with multithreading. The container is not at all threadsafe, other than `const` member functions, which can be accessed concurrently. The *multi* just means that the container will store duplicates, meaning keys that compare equal. A `set` will only store unique keys.

Comment: TonyD exactly what I thought when I made the comment "oops".
@Praetorian no, multiset doesn't touch multithreading, thankfully I haven't messed it up. :)

Comment: After all `map` was the most suitable data structure. @TonyD you have the feeling.

Comment: If not Greek then barbarian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you cannot pass a lambda (runtime construct) as a template parameter (compile-time construct). Using a struct with `operator()` works instead:

```
#include <set>
struct my_compare {
  bool operator() (const std::pair<float, int>& a, const std::pair<float, int>& b) {
    return (a.first < b.first && a.second != b.second);
  };
};
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  std::multiset<std::pair<float, int>, my_compare> set;
  return 0;
}
```

Or, with a lambda and decltype (as in Praetorian's answer):

```
#include <set>  
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  auto my_compare = [](const std::pair<float, int>& a, const std::pair<float, int>& b) {
    return (a.first < b.first && a.second != b.second);
  };
  std::multiset<std::pair<float, int>, decltype(my_compare)> set(my_compare);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do get a different error than you are seeing, on GCC 4.9: temp.cpp:13:40: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type.

Comment: The guy in the link I provided suggest that with the λ. Add `set.insert(std::make_pair(0.1, 1));` to see what it happens. There was a comment by @T.C. saying that multiset requires strong ordering, which our compar doesn't have!

Comment: Apparently the reason the insert() call fails is that the compiler is unhappy that the parameters are not const. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using a `multiset`, and not a `set`, multiple keys that compare equal will still be stored in the container, so I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about uniqueness.

Assuming you meant you only want the second element in the `pair` to affect ordering, you can use a lambda as follows:

```
auto f = [](std::pair<float, int> const& a, std::pair<float, int> const& b) {
  return a.second < b.second;
};
std::multiset<std::pair<float, int>, decltype(f)> m(f);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/681ce345130d1a58)

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the other answer because it came first and for fair play. :)

Comment: @G.Samaras You accept the best answer, there's no issue of fair play here. We are not playing a game. Those who use SO to gain reputation instead of knowledge are fools.

Comment: Good point @40two. I'll still keep the other answer, because it was first then. :)

Comment: MSVC 2013 Doesn't allow this yet.

Comment: @AndyG It's a bug, I've seen it reported on connect. The MSVC stdlib tries to default construct the comparator even when you pass in an instance. Edit: Found the bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727957/vc11-beta-compiler-fails-to-compile-lambda-key-comparer-for-maps-and-sets Apparently fixed in VS2015.